# Can Vim scroll by "window lines" rather than "buffer lines"?

Tags: scrolling

When scrolling in a document with long, wrapped lines, the document will jump up and down by multiple lines when the cursor reaches the top or bottom of the window. Vim always shows the beginning of a buffer line in the very top left of the window rather than, e.g., the last 2 window lines of a long buffer line that is wrapped into 5 window lines.

[**video demo**](https://i.imgur.com/avSNjNV.mp4)

- I am not referring to the cursor moving by buffer lines rather than window lines. `:noremap j gj` solves that problem.
- `:set display=lastline` helps by showing as much as possible, even if not all, of the last buffer line in the window, but doesn't affect scrolling.

I use the definitions of "window line" and "buffer line" from `:help window-contents`:

> A difference is made between four types of lines:
>
> - **buffer lines**
>   The lines in the buffer. This is the same as the lines as they are read from/written to a file. They can be
>   thousands of characters long.
> - **logical lines**
>   The buffer lines with folding applied. Buffer lines in a closed fold are changed to a single logical line: "+-- 99
>   lines folded". They can be thousands of characters long.
> - **window lines**
>   The lines displayed in a window: A range of logical lines with wrapping, line breaks, etc. applied. They can only
>   be as long as the width of the window allows, longer lines are wrapped
>   or truncated.
> - **screen lines**
>   The lines of the screen that Vim uses. Consists of the window lines of all windows, with status lines and the command
>   line added. They can only be as long as the width of the screen
>   allows. When the command line gets longer it wraps and lines are
>   scrolled to make room.